# SQL Selecting Top 1 with MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a parking citation database I am trying to select the state that has the most citations.

```
SELECT State, COUNT(Citation) as MostViolations
FROM dbo.ParkingCitations
GROUP BY State
ORDER BY COUNT(Citation) DESC
```

The syntax above will give me the top state in the first row, but I'm not sure how I got about selecting just that distinct state only?  (Should I be using a subquery with `TOP 1` somehow?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `TOP 1` does what you want:

```
SELECT TOP 1 State, COUNT(Citation) as MostViolations
FROM dbo.ParkingCitations
GROUP BY State
ORDER BY COUNT(Citation) DESC;
```

If you want all when there are ties, then use `top 1 with ties`.

Comment: Wow, I'm a dummy, it was so simple